# responsive iframe with SurveyMonkey

Tags: surveymonkey

I'm working on embedding a very quick survey on my site and after page one, there is just description text for page 2 and 3. So how do I a) make the iframe responsive to the number of questions or b) get rid the other ugly gray bottom when the description text appears? I don't mind the scroll bar but in a dream scenario what I would like is no scoll bar - all 4 questions fit on the page and then the continue button on page 2  shows up with no grey box.

The iframe code I have on the page is:

with the following CSS:

```
<style>
.survey-container {
position: relative;
}
iframe {
border-style: none;
background-color:transparent;
min-height: 400px; 
max-height: 600px; 
overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WP1dZ.jpg

Comment: I should note that I am open to ideas on embedding surveymonkey forms as I am not 100% sold on using an iframe

Comment: would using the embed div they supply help? https://www.surveymonkey.com/blog/2013/04/23/how-to-embed-your-survey-on-a-website/

Answer (score 1):

[Using the embed script provided by Surveymonkey](https://www.surveymonkey.com/blog/2013/04/23/how-to-embed-your-survey-on-a-website/), I was able to make the embedded survey `width:100%` by nullifying the max-width property through CSS:

```css
.smcx-embed {
     max-width: none !important;
}

.smcx-embed iframe {
     max-width: none !important;
}
```